# Fetch and Merge into all Branches at once from Upstream Repository

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-fetch, upstream-branch

I have a github fork, which I have cloned onto my computer. On the original project, I have opened many PRs, and each of them correspond to their own branch (I don't use `master`). From time to time, I occasionally run the following command:

```
git fetch upstream && git merge upstream/master --no-edit
```

(`upstream` is the original repository).

The command above works for updating the *current branch* that I am on. Is there a way to do the same for *all my branches at once*? Currently, to achieve the same behavior, I have to `git checkout` to all of the respective branches, and then do the sync, which I find quite tedious.

(I am quite new to `git`, so I would appreciate a good amount of explanation in an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do merge or rebase with non-current (not checked out) branch. Merge/rebase could have conflicts and the only way to resolve them is manually — hence the requirement to checkout the branch.

You can fetch non-current branches if all branches can be fast-forwarded. The command:

```
git fetch origin v1:v1 v2:v2
```

fetches named branches and fast-forwards them. But if branch cannot be fast-forwarded the only way to merge is to check it out and merge.

Comment: Ah, well that's unfortunate but helpful. I will mark this correct. I will remember the fast-forwarding command, which could be useful.